# How to get rid of System.UnauthorizedAccessException in WPF

Tags: c#, pdf, directory

I'm trying to write generated pdf file to the directory on Desktop, but System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access to the path is denied." appears every time. I tried to run Visual Studio as admin, but it didn't work.

PDF-generator method code:

```
public void GeneratePDF()
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Title = $"Чек №{_orderId}";

    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    XFont font = new XFont("Arial", 18);

    gfx.DrawString($"{document.Info.Title}", new XFont("Arial", 40, XFontStyle.Bold), XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(200, 70));

    document.Save(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CourseWorkPDFs");
}
```

Exception:
[image: Exception]

Comment: Better not hard-code the desktop directory, but get it from [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath)

Comment: Did you tried to write a file with the same path with simple `File.Write` or even manually with `notepad.exe`? Will it lead to the same error or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a filename, not only the name of the directory:

```
document.Save(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CourseWorkPDFs\FileName.pdf");
```

You'll have to modify the code to generate a unique filename from the orderid or the current date and time or using some other mechanism.